# How to express untyped links?

Tags: json-ld, linked-data, vocabulary

All examples I found use some vocabulary (like FOAF) to link to another resource (knows, spouse, member,...). Is there already a way (or commonly used vocabulary) to express a general "is related to" relation-type? You may also characterize such as link as "additional information here".

Google is surprisingly unhelpful at those topics. Is there any resource for link-relation-types?

Update:
This will get me a tumbleweed-badge ;)

schema.org has `relatedLink` and `isRelatedTo` properties, the latter one seems to be for products only. I can't find `relatedLink` by browsing the schema hieracy, only when searching for it, whats kind of strange too. They state its a property of `Thing`, but it's not listed there.

Would it be OK to give several links to relatedLink using an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there already a way (or commonly used vocabulary) to express a general "is related to" relation-type

There exists [rdfs:seeAlso](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_seealso) which is probably the most often used property for such a use case.

> Would it be OK to give several links to relatedLink using an array?

Yes. Unless otherwise specified, that's always allowed.

Comment: Thanks Markus. RDFS wasn't on my radar. I pigeonholed it as a way to make a vocabulary-definition machine readable.